# [[class]] property in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a simple clone function

```
var shallowCopy = function (value) {
  // in ES2017 we can use
  // return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(value), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(value));
  let propDescriptors = {};
  for (let i of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value)) {
    propDescriptors[i] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(value, i);
  }
  return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(value), propDescriptors);
};
```

I understand this behavior that `Object.prototype.toString.call(shallowCopy([]))` is `[object Object]` , not `[object Array]`.

But Some new types in ES6 look good

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(shallowCopy(new Set())) // [object Set]
Object.prototype.toString.call(shallowCopy(new Map())) // [object Map]
```

Can somebody tell me why these objects behave differently?
Will this behavior be changed in future?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no [[class]] field in ES6 any more, [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) works different now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specification defines special symbol used during constructing string representation of the object called `@@toStringTag`. See [Well-Known Symbols](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) section, specifically it describes *@@toStringTag* as

> A String valued property that is used in the creation of the default string description of an object. Accessed by the built-in method [Object.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring).

Now, if you check values of *@@toStringTag* for those types, for example for the [Set](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype-@@tostringtag):

**[23.2.3.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype-@@tostringtag) Set.prototype [ @@toStringTag ]**

> The initial value of the @@toStringTag property is the String value **"Set"**.

Feel free to check other types like Promise ([25.4.5.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype-@@tostringtag)), ArrayBuffer ([24.1.4.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraybuffer.prototype-@@tostringtag)), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you have demonstrated is not related to the `[[Class]]` of an object.

If you log `Map.prototype` you will see that these new types have a [`toStringTag` Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@toStringTag):

```
> Map.prototype
Map {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Map"}
```

The value of this Symbol property is used in generating the string produced by `toString()`. See [`Symbol.toStringTag` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

> A string value used for the default description of an object. Used by Object.prototype.toString().

I doubt this behaviour will change for pre-ES6 types, for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The object is not a set. Real sets have internal [[SetData]] slots which you can't replicate.

```
shallowCopy(new Set()).add(123); // TypeError: add method called on incompatible Object
```

Basically, don't trust the [[Class]] to know which kind of object you have. Well, in fact [[Class]] has been nuked in ES6 and no longer exists.